# JSON String can't get convert into object and get it's value

Tags: android, json

this is my JSON string `{"Success":0,"Message":"Something Went Wrong"}`   i try this

```
        if (jsonStr != null){
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            JSON_RESPONSE_Success = jsonObj.getJSONObject(TAG_Success);
            JSON_RESPONSE_Message = jsonObj.getJSONObject(TAG_Message);

             Log.d("TAG_Success: ", "> " + JSON_RESPONSE_Success);
             Log.d("TAG_Message: ", "> " + JSON_RESPONSE_Message);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }`
```

but it won't helping me. it's single object there is no array so need only two value to be parse from JSON to string.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: There are too many exactly same questions. Next time, please, use search. Also, [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) is very easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace your two `getJSONObject` by `getString` like this:

```
if (jsonStr != null){
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            JSON_RESPONSE_Success = jsonObj.getString(TAG_Success);
            JSON_RESPONSE_Message = jsonObj.getString(TAG_Message);

             Log.d("TAG_Success: ", "> " + JSON_RESPONSE_Success);
             Log.d("TAG_Message: ", "> " + JSON_RESPONSE_Message);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String JSON_RESPONSE_Success = jsonObj.getString(TAG_Success);
String JSON_RESPONSE_Message = jsonObj.getString(TAG_Message);
```